# How to get a proper and query with django where not exists statement

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I have this query which I would like to use as a filter:

```
select * from api_document ad 
where not exists (
select 1
from api_documentactionuser ad2 
where ad2.user_id=4 and ad2.action_id=3 and ad.id = ad2.document_id 
limit 1
)
```

What I've tried with django is:

```
q = queryset.exclude(
        Q(documentactionuser__action__id=3)
        & Q(documentactionuser__user=current_user),
    )
```

while queryset is a queryset on the api_document table. When I print the generated query however, django keeps separating the two conditions into two queries instead of simply using and, which in turn gives me the wrong data back:

```
select * FROM "api_document" 
WHERE NOT (
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "api_documentactionuser" U1 WHERE (U1."action_id" = 3 AND U1."document_id" = ("api_document"."id")) LIMIT 1) 
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "api_documentactionuser" U1 WHERE (U1."user_id" = 1 AND U1."document_id" = ("api_document"."id")) LIMIT 1)
    )
```

I've tried chaining exclude().exclude(), filter(~@()).filter(~@()) and the above variant and it all returns nearly the same query, with the same data output

Comment: You should be able to use `~Exists(<query>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `~Exists` and specify the queryset you want to check

```
queryset.filter(
    ~Exists(DocumentationActionUser.objects.filter(action__id=3).filter(user=current_user)
)
```

SHould do the trick (untested - just typed this directly here, so beware of typos! :) )

Comment: That looks nearly right:

`select COUNT(*) FROM "api_document" 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "api_documentactionuser" U0 WHERE (U0."action_id" = 3 AND U0."user_id" = 4) LIMIT 1)`


Now the only thing missing is the ad.id = ad2.document_id part. But I don't know how to access the queryset it inside the exists block?

Comment: Looks OK to me? What's wrong with it?

Comment: It returns 0 results, because the query inside exists should be `where ad2.user_id=4 and ad2.action_id=3 and ad.id = ad2.document_id `
But it's only filtering on `where ad2.user_id=4 and ad2.action_id=3 `

Comment: So add the extra `filter` to the query - I was going off your "what I've tried with django" :)

Comment: Yeah I realized that what I've tried was lacking in the first place just now :D
My problem is, I don't know how I can filter against the api_document from inside the Exists. If I try something like `.filter(document__id=id)` I naturally get the error that id is an python object. Would I have to use sth like ApiDocument.objects or how can I filter against the api_document there?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `id` in that code? You can either filter on just `document` and match it to an instance of the class, or you can filter `document__id` and match to the id value. Note the double underscore there, since (I assume) document is a FK?

Comment: Yeah so DocumentAcionUuser's `document` is a fk to `document_api`. In the raw sql above I could filter the fk (`ad2.document_id`) against the `api_document.id` field (`ad.id`). But in django I don't know how I could write this filter, as I don't know how to get the value from `api_document.id` (`ad.id`) inside the .filter().

Comment: Ah, that is an entirely different question, and requires a `Subquery` together with an `OuterRef` probably ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: Yes the OuterRef was, what I was looking for, thanks so much!
So my finally statement now is `q = queryset.filter(
            ~Exists(
                DocumentActionUser.objects.filter(action__id=3)
                .filter(user=current_user).filter(document=OuterRef("pk"))
            )
        )` which returns pretty much what the raw sql did :)